# Reading network service order on OS X

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I need to read the network service order on OS X. Is there a way it can be done using cocoa APIs? I know I can execute

```
networksetup -listnetworkserviceorder
```

and parse the output to get the same. I am looking for a cleaner solution.

Comment: Have you looked at the System Configuration framework? Yes it's poorly named.

Comment: @uchuugaka: System Config Framework doesn't seem to give this info. Any other way to get the network service order set by the user??

Comment: @seema Did you find any solution for this, please let me know if any. Thanks